# Sound of water filling up a bottle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, acoustics

So there are many questions addressing but I am yet to find a correct response. Most answers indicate that the bottle should be modeled as a Helmholtz resonator or as a closed organ pipe with decreasing height. However I am certain that there is more at play here. For instance, changing the temperature of water drastically changes the sound. Also changing the distance that the bottle is kept from the tap changes the frequency. I read up on this and I realized that maybe the sound heard was due to the splash and the Weber number but I still don't quite understand how. If someone could give a more detailed comprehensive answer to this question.  It would be appreciated.

Comment: Temperature influences the speed of sound, also because air with a high partial pressure of water is lighter. Does this explain the sign of the effect? And is it quantitatively correct for the Helmholtz resonator?

Comment: temperature does influence the speed of sound ,but the water is at a high temperature not the air. Also how could you write this as an equation

Comment: @IshaanParikh "the water is at a high temperature"? so define high... above ambient by how much or 99 deg C?

Comment: @SolarMike high as in 60 deg Celsius compared to 4 degrees celsius.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the sound of filling water into a bottle rise in its frequency?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/357512/why-the-sound-of-filling-water-into-a-bottle-rise-in-its-frequency)